# if statement in jQuery not working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
I have the following code that is working in IE 8 but not in Chrome or Safari:


 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.goRedIMG').on('click',function(event){
            var ischecked = false;
            var isOKtoSubmit = true;
            var alertMessage = 'No tools have been selected';
            var statusvar = '';
            var transferstatusvar = '';
            var action = $('#uTransaction option:selected').html();

            $('.chkaction').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                statusvar = $(this).closest('tr').children('.recordStatus').html();
                transferstatusvar = $(this).closest('tr').children('.transferstat').html()

                if($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    ischecked = true;
                    //alert(action);
                   // alert(statusvar);
                  //  alert(transferstatusvar);


                   if (action == 'Recover'){ 
                       if (statusvar != 'OOS'){
                          // alert(statusvar);
                            isOKtoSubmit = false;
                            alertMessage = 'One or more records cannot be recoverd due to status not   being OOS and Transfer Status not OK';               
                       }
                   }
if(isOKtoSubmit && ischecked !== false && action !== '--Select One--'){                 
                $('#toolActions').submit();         
            }else {
                alert(alertMessage);
            }
    });
```

If a user chooses Recover and chooses a record that has a status that is in 'OOS' they are getting the alert message in Chrome that the record does not have the correct status. In IE if you choose the same record the alert message does not appear and that would be correct.

Comment: try `$('#uTransaction option:selected').val()` or `$('#uTransaction option:selected').text();`

Comment: I might suggest a little more clarity in your conditional>

if(isOKtoSubmit && (ischecked !== false) && (action !== '--Select One--'))

Comment: Which statement isn't working? `if (action == 'Recover')` or `if (statusvar != 'OOS')`? Also try using `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: I think it does not like the if (statusvar != 'OOS'). Per your suggestion I put in .text() in var action = $('#uTransaction option:selected').text(); and that does not fix it. I also tried .val and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use your code like this:

```
  var action = 'Recover';
  var statusvar = 'OOS';

  if (action == 'Recover') {
      if (statusvar != 'OOS') {

          alert('One or more records cannot be recoverd due to status not   being OOS and Transfer Status not OK'); 

      }
  }
```

in both browsers it runs correctly. I think you have problem with your data.

In your original code try to use

```
alert(statusvar + ' - length:' + statusvar.length)
```

And check the character lenght of the variable. This way you can see if there is any funny character in your statusvar variable.

Comment: That was it. The length of OOS was 4 so there must be a space in there. Thanks for that. I did not think it would be that since it was working in IE.